# jQuery Mobile Submit form returns me to home page not next page

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am building a small app in jQuery mobile.

I am having a problem when going from one page to another when submitting a form.

So my first page look like this

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a"  id="page1">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <a  data-icon="back"
            data-iconpos="notext"
            data-rel="back"
            data-transition="slidefade"
            >Info</a>
        <a href="#home"
            data-icon="home"
            data-iconpos="notext"
            data-transition="slidefade"
            >Home</a>

    </div>

 <div class="pageContainer">     
    <section id="links">

    <form name="page1" method="post" action="#page2" id="form">

    <div  class="panel colourPanel">


        <div class="searchMethod buttonColour even">

            <input name="hidBranch" type="hidden" id="hidBranch" value="0" />
            <div class="searchText textShadow">Branch</div>
            <div class="searchImg">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <div class="searchMethod buttonColour odd">

           <input name="hidATM" type="hidden" id="hidATM" value="0" />
            <div class="searchText textShadow">ATM</div>
            <div class="searchImg">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <div class="searchInput">
            <input id="searchArea"  type="text" value="Search address">
        </div>

        <div id="searchContainer">
            <input type="submit" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch2" alt="Find" value="Search" />

        </div>

    </div>

    </form>


      </section>

</div>
```

so i am expecting this to go to the page2 but instead it goes back to the root page?

Why would this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Is your HTML not lacking another page?
`<div data-role="page" id="page2">`

Answer (score 0):

Your content must wrapped inside this div:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" id="someid"></div>
```

You need to have a data-role="content" if you want a content inside jQM page.

Comment: even with that div it doesnt go to the next page.

its adds the #page2 to the url but doesnt go to the next page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still working on this or solved it but I thought I would post a solution for others out there with this problem.

jQM defaults to returning your app to the "first page" after a form submit.  You can use the following (taken from the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html)) to change the default.  jQM is listening for a call to `pagebeforechange` event, to update the defaults, as it processes the form and navigation.

```
// Listen for any attempts to call changePage().
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {

    // We only want to handle changePage() calls where the caller is
    // asking us to load a page by URL.
    if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {

        // We are being asked to load a page by URL, but we only
        // want to handle URLs that request the data for a specific
        // category.
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ),
            re = /^#category-item/;

        if ( u.hash.search(re) !== -1 ) {

            // We're being asked to display the items for a specific category.
            // Call our internal method that builds the content for the category
            // on the fly based on our in-memory category data structure.
            showCategory( u, data.options );

            // Make sure to tell changePage() we've handled this call so it doesn't
            // have to do anything.
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```